# Keras predicting and updating the neuron weights at the same time

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have built (model.compile()) a Neural Network model using Keras. Then I have fitted the model (model.fit()) using my train data. Finally, I am using the model to predict (model.predict()) the values of the test data.

Based on my understanding, in the process of fitting the model, the weights of the neurons of the network are being updated in each batch. Is this still the case, when predicting? Do the weights of the neural network get updated for each batch when predicting? Is there a possibility to switch this option on and off? I am running two analyses and in the first one, I would like the weights not to update when predicting but in the other one I would like the weights to update for each batch.

Answer (score 0):

Weights do not update when predicting, only when training and hence only for Model.fit

Comment: Is there a way to make it update the weights while predicting. If not, how could that be achieved, it seems pretty convoluted.

Comment: If you update weight while predicting it is called training.
Prediction is usually used to test with different data than training, to validate model and to make sure there is no over-fitting.  For your problem, you can predict, save the model and then retrain with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

The weights are updated after each batch in the training process, after you train the model, you can save it and then use:

```
# Save model
model.save('saved_model.h5')
# Loading saved model weights
model.load_weights('saved_model.h5')
```

and then use the saved model to predict the test data values.

If you want to make any changes to updating process, you can change the hyperparameters related to weights updating including the *number of epochs* and *batch size*.

Answer (score 0):

The backpropagation algorithm uses the inital weights and optimized them via iteration process. Let's assume that you have stored your training model (optimized weights calculated via backpropagation algorithm), then the model is loaded again. Now, you have a bunch of new data and need to update your last weights based on them. Thus, try the following script in which X and y are the new data:

```
if old_model_weights_modified=='Yes':
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(modelpath)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=60, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
    predictions = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(X))
```

In other words, the "load_model" command loads the latest model's weights and "model.fit" command considers them as the initial weights and updates the initial weights based on the new data.